# How does request isolation work in CherryPy. I don't understand the basic concept

Tags: python, cherrypy

In short, I don't understand that what happens it CherryPy GETs two requeste to same resource at the same time, are variables mixed or what is happening ?

I have this problem, I am trying to create a very basic web service with Python 2.7 and CherryPy 3.2.2.

Web service is consumed by front end which makes ajax requests to web service with jquery/ajax.

Now, I have created a CherryPy program and I am using its builtin wsgi server. I have CherryPy configuration like this:

```
conf = {
    'global': {
        'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1',
        'server.socket_port': 8000,
    },
    '/': {
        'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
    }
}
cherrypy.quickstart(root, '/', conf)
```

And then I have:

```
root.customers = getCustomers()
```

And the actual class for this:

```
class getCustomers(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    exposed = True

    def GET(self,callback,**kwargs):
        self.callback = callback
        self.cnxn= pyodbc.connect(constr)
        self.cursor = self.cnxn.cursor()

        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type']='application/json'
        self.cursor.execute("""select * from customers
            """, self.job_worknumber)
        self.customers = self.cursor.fetchall()

        self.objects_list = []
        for c in self.customers
            r = collections.OrderedDict()
            r['customer_id'] = c.customer_id
            r['customer_name'] = c.customer_name
            self.objects_list.append(r)

        self.cursor.close()
        self.cnxn.close()

        self.w = collections.OrderedDict()
        self.w['data1'] = self.objects_list
        #w['errors'] = 'error'
        self.j = json.dumps(self.w)

        #cursor2.close()
        return  self.callback+'('+self.j+');'
```

Now when I create a GET request to that I get what I want, but if I create web page which sends two GET request to web service at page load the second request will almost always fail with an error like:

```
ProgrammingError: Attempt to use a closed cursor.
```

Or other times:

```
ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query
```

So what is happening, are my requests sharing same variables it they are run at the very same time ? Can I configure CherryPy to only serve one request at a time ?

Comment: I don't know cherrypy, but you're setting a lot of attributes on `self` there, which might be your problem. Since they're only used within the method itself, you could try just using local variables instead.

Comment: Can you narrow it down to just calling the database in a function directly and check that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DanielRoseman noticed you should not set variables on `self`. You have create only one instance of `getCustomers` class so CherryPy will call `GET` method on the same instance from multiple threads (there's a thread pool which handles requests). Therfore using

```
self.cursor = self.cnxn.cursor()
```

is not thread-safe and you end up with different cursor in

```
self.cursor.execute("""select * from customers
            """, self.job_worknumber)
```

or `self.cursor.fetchall()` or in any other place (it is a bit random).

However changing all variables to local (don't use `self` at all in `GET`) should fix the problem.